# Remove any multiple points or any decimal points after the first one in java when converting string to double

Tags: java, double

I am having a string which may have a value like 1000.021 which i then convert to double using the method below

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(1000.021);
```

This just works fine when its a single decimal place but when i get a sting value like 1000.021.2344.455 it crashes on parsing the double from String to double how can i be able to remove the extra decimal places after the first one so the i have a double like 1000.0212344455 when i get a value like 1000.021.2344.455

Below is what i have tried but it just removes all the decimal places and it just accepts a number with a single decimal place in the .format

```
new DecimalFormat("#").format(100.22);
```

Comment: Technically `1000.021.2344.455` is not a number. So you need to use string operations for your task. The task itself however seems pretty questionable.

Comment: Are you certain it is not a thousands separator (and for decimal separator a comma is used)? You could do `s = s.replaceAll("(?=.*\.)\.", "");` before formatting (regex lookahead of period.

Comment: @JoopEggen yes i am certain i required this to handle erroneous input so that incase of two decimal places input any multiple decimal places input after the first one will be removed and Prog_G answered well

Comment: @dpr thats why programming is fun the task is just okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code for the conversion:

```
    public static double toDouble(String s) {
        int i1 = s.indexOf(".");
        return Double.parseDouble(s.substring(0, i1 + 1) + s.substring(i1).replaceAll("\\.", ""));
    }
```

**Test case:**

```
@Test
public void test(){
    double v = toDouble("1000.021.2344.455");
    assert v == 1000.0212344455;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried that one:

```
String str = "1000.021.2344.455";
    String newStr = "";
    boolean dot = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '.' && dot) {
            newStr +=str.charAt(i);
            dot =false;
        }
        if(str.charAt(i) != '.' || dot){
            newStr +=str.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    Double num = Double.parseDouble(newStr);
    System.out.println(num);
```

Output: 1000.0212344455